# Azure B2C - How to skip sign in page for profile edit flow on mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

According to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-profile-editing-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. The profile edit flow will show the Sign-up or sign-in page, if there are no active session. If the session is active, then Azure AD B2C authorizes the user, and skips to the next step.

However, if I understand correctly, this 'session' would be in the form of a cookie right? If that's the case, what would happen with mobile apps?

Mobile app doesn't use cookies. After login in, they only have the `id token`, `access token` and `refresher token`. So if a user is logs in on an app, and then to do a profile edit flow, how would the app tell the browser that the user is already logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the web view redirect flow, a cookie is set in the web view which then gives SSO for profile edit. You don’t need to configure anything in B2C to make it behave like this, it’s default.

Comment: According to the `user journey behaviors` documentation, The maximum session time for a web view is only 24 hours.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#userjourneybehaviors 

But the user might be logged into an app for many months at a time. If we rely on the web view session cookie, it means that a user who is logged in on the app, when they go to edit their profile, they'll need to log in again. Is there any way around this? Is it possible for the app to pass the access token to the web view so the user don't need to manually log in again?

Comment: Use [Keep Me Signed In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi) for long lived persistent sessions.

Comment: And technically yes, you can pass an `access_token` to the webview as an `id_token_hint` to skip the credential screen (bootstraps the journey).  There is a [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) which demonstrated the usage of `id_token_hint`. The concept can be used to bootstrap any journey. MSAL [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#pass-an-id-token-hint) this parameter also.